# C# Can´t just get to add values to 2D matrix from console

Tags: c#, matrix

Need help with this program. It´s almost done, but still have some issues to solve. This is the complete code

```
 object[,] data = new object[5, 5];

    //Adding values to matrix
    public void load()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split('=');
                string[] coordinates = input[0].Split(',');

                int[] intCoordinates = coordinates.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

                data[intCoordinates[0], intCoordinates[1]] = int.Parse(input[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Viewing matrix created
    public void view()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "\n" + "Matrix created is:");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(data[i, j].ToString());
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program objeto = new Program();
        char letter;

    //Main menu
    menu:
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "WELCOME" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n");
        Console.Write("Select an option:" + "\n" + "\n");
        Console.Write("\t" + "a) Add value to matrix" + "\n");
        Console.Write("\t" + "b) View matrix" + "\n");
        Console.Write("\t" + "c) End" + "\n");
        letter = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a':
                {
                    add:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Set value in:" + "\n" + "\n");
                    objeto.load();
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another value Y/N" + "\n" + "\n");
                    letter = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

                    switch (letter)
                    {
                        case 'y':
                            {
                                goto add;
                            }

                        case 'n':
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Returning to Main Menu");
                                Console.Clear();
                                goto menu;
                            }

                        default:
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Error, returning to Main Menu");
                                Console.Clear();
                                goto menu;
                            }
                    }

                }

            case 'b':
                {
                    objeto.view();
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine("Returning to Main Menu");
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto menu;
                }

            case 'c':
                {
                    goto end;
                }

            default:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, try again");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto menu;
                }
        }

        //Ending menu
    end:
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "\n" + "¿Exit program? S/N");
        letter = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'n':
                {
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto menu;
                }

            case 's':
                {
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    Console.Write("\n" + "\n" + "Error, try again");
                    goto end;
                }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Closing, press any key");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

So, the program is supposed to create a 5x5 matriz, and, then from console, the user should be able to add an * (only *, that´s why im using "object"), anywhere he wants to, let´s say for example row 2 column 4. The program should also let the user view the matrix with all the * added and navigate the program tru menus, which are working just fine.

I already posted parts of the program before, and have solved several problems, so this time we go for final "details". The program can be used, but then:

1.- Load code is not working correctly, while running i always get IndexOutOfRangeException when adding a number or FormatException when adding the *. So the code has a mistake or either i don´t know how to set the value in from console.

2.- View code throws NullReferenceException, but i think it´s becasuse the matrix is empty, but i always thought that when created and not assigned values, matrix values were 0´s by defalut.

3.- How can i get the user to use only * for the program?

Help´ll be greatly appreciated  n_n

Comment: If you want a protip to debug your code : Get rid of the `Goto`s... I can understand why you're having a hard time with that code.

Comment: I use goto because it was requested for the program. Seems lots of people hate´em. Anyway, the main problem is the process of input values in the matrix. I just can´t. Is the program working correctly?